# Bash alias query

Tags: bash, find, grep, alias

How can I turn the following command into a bash alias?

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs grep --color -n 'search term'
```

Where I can specify the file extension and 'search term' is obviously the search term :)

So what I want to do is:

```
 searchFiles 'php' 'search term'
```

How do I pass the input into the alias? Should I just create a bash script and have the alias point to the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using a function? Add this to your .bashrc:

```
function searchFiles() {
       find . -name \*."$1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n "$2"
}
```

and then use it like:

<kbd>$ searchFiles c include</kbd>

Comment: As **Chris Johnsen** states, you should use `-print0` and `-0`

Answer (score 5):

You could use an alias, but using a function, like Gonzalo shows, the sane thing to do.

```
alias searchFiles=sh\ -c\ \''find . -name \*."$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -Hn "$2"'\'\ -
```

Whether function or alias, I recommend using `-print0` with *find* and `-0` with *xargs*. This provides for more robust filename handling (most commonly, spaces in filenames).

Answer (score 1):

While a function works, it won't be callable from other programs and scripts (without a lot of pain).  (An alias would have the same problem.)  A separate script would be my choice, since it sounds like you want to invoke it directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# since you're already using bash, depend on it instead of /bin/sh
# and reduce surprises later (you can always come back and look at
# porting this)

INCLUDE="*.$1"
PATTERN="$2"
grep --color -n "$PATTERN" --recursive --include="$INCLUDE" .
```

(No need for find with what you have.)

If this was only used inside another script instead of directly, a function would be easier.

Comment: You can `export` a function to make it available to other scripts. If there are a large number of files it may make sense to use `find` and `xargs`. I don't see anything in your script that's Bash-specific. I think the Bourne shell would be perfectly happy with it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's not as easy for someone unfamiliar to grasp than just executing a script.  Why do you think find+xargs would be better?  Re sh, I was just pointing out that he doesn't have to worry about "bash vs sh" (which can be a PITA) just because he's writing a separate script---just write a bash script.

Comment: I agree with @Roger. Assuming you have your own private "~/bin" directory in your path in which to keep it (you do, don't you? :),  a stand-alone script is always more flexible and robust for little commands you want to use both directly in the cli and inside other scripts.  A directory of small sripts is easier to deal with than a single file full of unrelated functions, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Shell functions are good, but you may also want to take a look at [ack](http://betterthangrep).  It handles file-specific searching, with color-coding, so that your example would simply be

```
ack --php somepattern
```